# Entity Framework - How to access foreign key not listed in Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, foreign-keys

I have the following two entities,

```
public class App
{
public int AppID { get; set; }
public string Business { get; set; }
public string ApName { get; set; }
public string FirstContact { get; set; }
}


public class Colleague
{
public int ColleagueID { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string SecondName { get; set; }
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<App> Apps { get; set; }
}
```

in my SQL table this automatically created a foriegn key property for the App model that refers to the ColleagueID.

My issue is that since the foriegn key isn't mentioned in the actual model, how do i use it in queries? for example, i want to show all the apps where the foreign key matches that of the given colleague ID.

Comment: Essential reading:  Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You're on a right track. You need to populate the foreign key for the `App` class. This is a perfect example of one-to-many relationship.

```
public class App
{
    public int AppID { get; set; }
    public string Business { get; set; }
    public string ApName { get; set; }
    public string FirstContact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Colleague")]
    public int ColleagueId { get; set; }
    public virtual Colleague Colleague { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can call `App.CollegueId` or `App.Colleague.CollegueId` anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you don't want to use [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx) and want that `Colleague` be optional when you save `App` to DB, you can use [Fluent Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx). First, add `ColleagueId` FK property to your `App` class:

```
public class App
{
  //...
  public int? ColleagueId { get; set; }
}
```

And then override the `OnModelCreating` method on your Context:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        modelBuilder.Entity<App>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.Colleague)
            .WithMany(c => c.Apps)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.ColleagueId);
 }
```

Now, this way you can do this query:

```
int selectedColleagueId = 1;
var apps=context.Apps.Where(a => a.ColleagueId == selectedColleagueId);
```

However, as @tschmit007 shows in his answer you don't need to expose the FK if you want just searching  for that value. FK property is very useful when you need to update a relationship, for example,  when you may not have the `Coleague` object in memory, but you do have access to that object’s key value. With a foreign key property, you can simply use the key value without depending on having that instance in memory:

```
app.ColleagueId=3;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

well one solution is :

```
IQueryable<Apps> q = ctx.Colleagues.Where(x => x.ColleagueID == someId).
    SelectMany(x => x.Apps);
```

you will not see the table backing `Colleague` in the generated SQL query. You'll get something like:

```
SELECT
    [Extend1].[AppID] AS [AppID],
    ...
FROM [dbo].[Apps] AS [Extend1]
WHERE 123 = [Extend1].[Colleague_ColleagueID]
```

where `Colleague_ColleagueID` is handled by EF and only by EF

So, there is no need, for the reasons you give, to expose a FK in your class.